# Collapse binary Pandas Dataframe into one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe of the form:

```py
  a b c d e
0 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1
2 1 1 0 0 0
```

I would like to collapse it taking only the ones to only one row, like:

```
   x 
0 'bd' 
1 'de' 
2 'ab'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in first output row should be 'bd' not 'be'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `dot`

```
df['x']=df.dot(df.columns)
```